# Display sumoselect in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sumoselect.js

I am using a [sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) for selection , and this sumoselect is in to the bootstrap modal.

But when i open dropdown then scrollbar is add and i have to scroll for see the dropdown options.

If i remove below css then it work ,but if i remove that css then it effect my entire application.

```js
$('.testselect10').SumoSelect();
```

```css
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <select style="width:200px;"  name="somename10" class="testselect10">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
            <option value="porsche">Porche</option>
            <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
            <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
            <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display like this:

[image]

Comment: So you don't want scrollbar in dropdown menu right?

Comment: @ManishPatel, check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add css which was affect for this modal only

```js
$('.testselect10').SumoSelect();
```

```css
#myModal .modal-body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: inherit;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <select style="width:200px;"  name="somename10" class="testselect10">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
            <option value="porsche">Porche</option>
            <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
            <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
            <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have to check that after changing `overflow` it is affect other places or not.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `overflow-y: auto` from `.modal-body` class.

```js
$('.testselect10').SumoSelect();
```

```css
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <select style="width:200px;"  name="somename10" class="testselect10">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
       <option value="porsche">Porche</option>
       <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
       <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
       <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I know that if i remove `overflow-y:auto` it is work , but  i don't want to remove that.

Comment: if you can use https://jsfiddle.net/ and show us your example because the solution is what @Ovidiu Unguru stated

Answer (score 0):

Try removing position absolute from sumoselect options container div.

Add below css in your code and enjoy!

```
<style type="text/css">

    .SumoSelect >.optWrapper
     {
       position:relative;        
     }
     .SumoSelect.open > .optWrapper
     {
        top:0;
     }

</style>
```

[image: Sumoselect under Bootstrap modal]